# In java what is the correct Class generic to use for Enum.valueOf()?

Tags: java, generics

I have a setup like this

```
interface A {}

enum B implements A {
    TEST;
}

class C<T extends Enum<? extends A>> {
    public C(T t) {
        T test = (T) T.valueOf(t.getClass(), "TEST");
    }
}
```

which works...however ideally I'd like to change C to be something like

```
class C<T extends Enum<? extends A>> {
    public C(Class<T> t) {
        T test = (T) T.valueOf(t, "TEST");
    }
}
```

however doing the second doesn't compile. What is the correct Class<> generic to use here? `Class<? extends Enum>` works but then I get a warning about a raw generic. Using `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` brings me back to an error. I know I can just use the first option and call `getClass()`, or even just suppress the warning for the raw generic but I want to understand what the correct generic type is...or am I just in Java generics hell and is there no right answer without suppressing the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `&` to ensure that `T` is an `enum` and implements `A`:

```java
class C<T extends Enum<T> & A> {
    public C(Class<T> t) {
        T test = Enum.valueOf(t, "TEST");
    }
}
```

Comment: O_O...not only does this fix my problem but it fixes my unchecked cast warning too...TIL, thanks!